# What is the best practice to segment c#.net projects based on a single base project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Honestly, I can't word my question any better without describing it.

- I have a base project (with all its glory, dlls, resources etc) which is a CMS.
- I need to use this project as a base for othe custom bake projects.
- This base project is to be maintained and updated among all custom bake projects.
- I use subversion (Collabnet and Tortise SVN)

I have two questions:

1 - **Can I use subversion to share the base project among other projects**

What I mean here is can I "Checkout" the base project into another "Checked Out" project and have both update and commit seperatley. So, to paint a picture, let's say I am working on a custom project and I modify the core/base prject in some way *(which I know will suit the others)* can I then commit those changes and upon doing so when I update the base project in the other "Checked out" resources will it pull the changes? In short, I would like not to have to manually deploy updated core files whenever I make changes into each seperate project.

2 - **If I create a custom file (let's say an webcontrol or aspx page etc) can I have it compile seperatley from the base project**

Another tricky one to explain. When I publish my web application it creates DLLs based on the namespaces of projects attached to it. So I may have a number of DLLs including the "Website's" namespace DLL, which could simply be website. I want to be able to make a seperate, custom, control which does not compile into those DLLs as the custom files should not rely on those DLLS to run. Is it as simple to set a seperate namespace for those files like CustomFiles.ProjectName for example?

Think of the whole idea as adding modules to the .NET project, I don't want the module's code in any of the core DLLs but I do need for module to be able to access the core dlls.

*(There is no need for the core project to access the module code as it should be one way only in theory, though I reckon it woould not be possible anyway without using JSON/SOAP or something like that, maybe I am wrong.)*

I want to create a pluggable environment much like that of Joomla/Wordpress as since PHP generally doesn't have to be compiled first I see this is the reason why all this is possible/easy. The idea is to allow pluggable themes, modules etc etc.

*(I haven't tried simply adding .NET themes after compile/publish but I am assuming this is possible anyway? OR does the compiler need to reference items in the files?)*

---

**UPDATE (16/05/2010):**

I posted a similar question with a little more detail for question 2 on [Experts-Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_26189055.html). I don't want to post all that info here as it just will be too messy but it explains question 2 in greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you want to use svn externals. More details can be found here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

For your second question, you need to create a seperate assembly and the easiest way is to create a new project within your solution. You can't have a single project emit 2 dll's (that I know of)

Comment: Yes, SVN externals seems the way to go here and is exactly what I was looking for as for question 1. I haven't tried to if a single project will allow mutliple Dlls but creating a seperate project seems more logical anyway. I read up a post in realtion to this (http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/8191.aspx) and I have yet to try it. My only concern is, yes, this method allows me to store custom controls, aspx pages, and resources in a seperate DLL and is logically what I am looking for, it seems I have to create a http handler. I'm not familiar with this, can it be in the custom assembly?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

If the base project is a library then there is nothing stopping you from creating the following directory structure on your SVN:

- **Base project**
- **Cool project nr 1**
- **Cool project nr 2**

All projects built on the **Base project** will include a relative reference and then everybody can checkout his **Cool project X** and the **Base project** and work on them. Checking-in changes for **Base project** will allow everybody else to see them by updating their **Base project** image. *Advantage*: only one SVN trunk required.

For your second question :

I tried my best, but I can't understand what you're asking :).

Comment: In ways I like your idea for queston and while it's not a wrong answer, it doesn't suit what I am doing, svn externals seems the way to go. You did help me solve another issue I was having.